# Tensor product and localization

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

This is from Liu, problem 1.2.2.

> Let $\rho:A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$, and $T=\rho (S)$. Show that $T^{-1}B\simeq B\otimes_AS^{-1}A$ as $A$-algebras.

I managed to prove that $T$ is a multiplicative subset of $B$ but how can I prove the isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Define $B \times S^{-1}A \to T^{-1}B, (b, \dfrac{a}{s}) \mapsto \dfrac{b \rho(a)}{\rho(s)}.$ Show that this is $A$-bilinear. Hence it will induce an unique map $ \phi: B\otimes_AS^{-1}A \to T^{-1}B$ and this is clearly surjective. To prove that $\phi$ is injective, first show that every element of $B\otimes_AS^{-1}A$ can be wriiten of the form $b \otimes \dfrac{1}{s}$ for some $b \in B, s \in S.$ Now $\phi(b \otimes \dfrac{1}{s}) = 0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{b}{\rho(s)} = 0 \Rightarrow tb = 0$ for some $t \in T.$ But then $t = \rho(s')$ for some $s' \in S.$ So $b \otimes \dfrac{1}{s} = b \otimes \dfrac{s'}{ss'} = \rho(s')b \otimes \dfrac{1}{ss'} = 0.$

Comment: I had trouble on proving the A-bilinearity with respect to the second parameter. Why do $(b,a_1/s_1+a_2/s_2)$ can be "splitted" into the parts $(b,a_1/s_1)$ and $(b,a_2/s_2)$?

Comment: $(b, \dfrac{a_1}{s_1} + \dfrac{a_2}{s_2}) = (b, \dfrac{s_2a_1 + s_1a_2}{s_1s_2}) \mapsto \dfrac{b \rho(s_2a_1 + s_1a_2)}{\rho(s_1s_2)}.$ Now use the the fact that $\rho: A \to B$ is a ring homomorphism to conclude that the above is equal to $\dfrac{b\rho(a_1)}{\rho(s_1)} + \dfrac{b\rho(a_2)}{\rho(s_2)}$ which is the image of $(b, \dfrac{a_1}{s_1}) + (b, \dfrac{a_2}{s_2}).$